# Connecting activities to GestureListener

Tags: java, android, gesturedetector

I have 10 activities in which I want to detect gestures. So I have created a class which implements `OnGestureListener`. This class also extends `GestureDetector` for `onTouchEvent()`. To connect all activities to this class, I instantiate this gesture listener class. The issue that I am facing is I can't pass the context (passes by other activites to this class) and `this` to super class. here is the code:

```
public class GestureReader extends GestureDetector implements OnGestureListener{

      public GestureReader(Context con)
  {
    super(con,this); // error here

    contxt= con;
    gestures = new GestureDetector(con,this);
  }

    @Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent me) {
    return gestures.onTouchEvent(me);
}

   .....
}
```

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the more clean solution would be to instantiate a new `GestureDetector`/`GestureReader` for each activity.

According to doc the `GestureDetector` would also be happy with the `Application`'s context so you can retrieve the `Application` from one of your activities to feed it to the detector

Comment: The other method I tried is, I am not extending GestureDetector in above mentioned class and created another class whcih extends GestureDetector, I have override OnTouchEvent() in that class. I am instantiating that class which is extending GestureDetector, in other activities but it seems like the onTouchEvent is not listening to gestures.

Comment: @user2498079 Maybe I understand you wrong but it is normally not necessary to override `onTouchEvent()` of the `GestureDetector` but to call it from the `onTouchEvent()` of a `View` where you overrode it. The detector then processes the events and calls in turn the `OnGestureListener`

Answer (score 0):

you can create base Activity that handles gestures and all your 10 Activities extend this base Activity